# Referencing include parameters in forloop construction

Tags: jekyll, liquid

My project has various files in the `_data` folder (eg: `list1.yml`, `list2.yml`, `list3.yml`) and I'm looking for a flexible way to generate a `for` loop by passing a parameter into an include, like so:

`{% include loop.html list="list1" %}`

In `loop.html` I have:

```
{% capture listToUse %}{{ include.list }}{% endcapture %}
{% for item in site.data.listToUse %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

However, when I run this, nothing happens. Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`site.data.listToUse` is not a correct expression, you need to enclose your variable in brackets : `site.data[listToUse]`.

```
{% assign listToUse = include.list %}

{% for item in site.data[listToUse] %}
  {{ item | inspect }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much. I wasn't aware of the bracket usage like that - would you mind pointing me in some docs around how/when to use it?